# Create builder with pre-built subtree in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In Flutter doc https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html, under Performance Optimization it states:

```
If your builder function contains a subtree that does not depend on the value of the ValueListenable, it's more efficient to build that subtree once instead of rebuilding it on every animation tick.

If you pass the pre-built subtree as the child parameter, the ValueListenableBuilder will pass it back to your builder function so that you can incorporate it into your build.

Using this pre-built child is entirely optional, but can improve performance significantly in some cases and is therefore a good practice.
```

Is there a more "general" builder widget that accepts pre-built subtree (similar to the mentioned `ValueListenableBuilder`) that is available in Flutter Widgets Catalog? If not, how does something like this work so I can create my own?

I looked at the source code but I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own.

```
class SubtreeBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  const SubtreeBuilder({
    Key key,
    @required this.builder,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, Widget child) builder;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return builder(context, child);
  }
}
```